# Adding Event Listeners to Play, Pause, and Skip to Seconds in HTML5 Video

Tags: javascript, html, video, addeventlistener

I have an HTML5 video that I'm using to show how a product works. When each image of a number is clicked, I want it to skip to a certain time in the video and then stop at a certain time.

Here is the code I am currently using that isn't working:

```html
<img id="stepOne" src="http://9e9.921.myftpupload.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/Step-1.png" /><img id="stepTwo" src="http://9e9.921.myftpupload.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/Step-2.png" /><img id="stepThree" src="http://9e9.921.myftpupload.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/Step-3.png" />

<video id="myvideo" width="300" height="150">
<source src="/videos/howitworks.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
<source src="/videos/howitworks.webm" type="video/webm=" />
Your browser does not support HTML5 video.</video>
```

With the Javascript

```html
var myvideo = document.getElementById('myvideo')
var stepone = document.getElementById('stepOne')
var steptwo = document.getElementById('stepTwo')
var stepthree = document.getElementById('stepThree')

stepone.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    myvideo.play();
    myvideo.pause();
    myvideo.currentTime = 0;
    myvideo.play();
}, false);


steptwo.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    myvideo.play();
    myvideo.pause();
    myvideo.currentTime = 10;
    myvideo.play();
}, false);


stepthree.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    myvideo.play();
    myvideo.pause();
    myvideo.currentTime = 32;
    myvideo.play();
}, false);
```

It can be viewed live [here](http://9e9.921.myftpupload.com/test-page/).

I haven't added anything in to make it stop when it hits a certain time because this current script isn't executing at all. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I go to your page I see the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null`, so perhaps this is your problem :)

The script is likely running before the elements are ready. Try wrapping that code in a `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {` and see if that fixes things?

So

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  var myvideo = document.getElementById('myvideo')
  var stepone = document.getElementById('stepOne')
  var steptwo = document.getElementById('stepTwo')
  var stepthree = document.getElementById('stepThree')

  stepone.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      myvideo.play();
      myvideo.pause();
      myvideo.currentTime = 0;
      myvideo.play();
  }, false);


  steptwo.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      myvideo.play();
      myvideo.pause();
      myvideo.currentTime = 10;
      myvideo.play();
  }, false);


  stepthree.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      myvideo.play();
      myvideo.pause();
      myvideo.currentTime = 32;
      myvideo.play();
  }, false);
});
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you so much for your help!